# Nothing I do remains after restart

Tags: hard-drive, format

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from a CD on my 64GB SSD. I made 2 partitions; 10GB for swap and the rest for the OS. I formatted them as ext4.

Ubuntu ran fine, but I am facing a strange problem. No matter what I do, It is ok to log out and back in, but It does not hold after a restart. If I change some settings, after a restart it is gone, I installed wine & some Windows application in wine; they worked fine, but after reboot they are gone. Even if I delete something from my desktop, it appears again on the desktop after reboot. I added Skype to my startup applications, but after reboot, it is no longer in the startup applications.

I can't format the whole drive & reinstall Ubuntu. I tried gparted, disk utility etc. I even tried with a xp cd, but no change remains. Maybe my drive gets locked, so that any change vanishes after reboot. what can I do now?

Comment: Trying to get things clear: Your post has some strange elements; you say you formatted both partitions as ext4, while swap is `linux-swap` format, furthermore, 10GB is extremely large for a swap area?

Comment: the swap wanst format with ext4, the remain 54 GB was in ext4

Answer (score 1):

I know this may sound strange, but is the live cd still in the computer? It could be possible your still booting into the demo of ubuntu.

Comment: nope. the live cd isnt in the computer. i did managed to install some program like skype, chrome on my desktop. they r still remain. from yesterday i installed wine then some other apps. but the wine gone, apps gone, even i installed gparted, it also gone. i deleted some files from desktop, also from trash. the appear again after reboot.